# Where are GTA Vice City NPC Skins located?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-vice-city

I've been trying to locate the skin files of NPCs. Would anyone know where in the root directory they might be located in? (With disk installation.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**C:/ProgramFiles/Steam/SteamApps/common/Grand Theft Auto Vice City/skins**

It'll only work to start if you downloaded the game off Steam legitimately (such as with an activation key, or purchase of the game). If you obtained the game through pirating, ROM, or other unofficial means, the root link above will not function and will lead to nowhere.

If the above link does not work, remove the spaces in-between the words, "Grand Theft Auto Vice" to look like "GrandTheftAutoVice", keeping all other text in the link the same.

This link should bring you to a file with the skins and textures of object(s) and NPCs.

Comment: I bought the game disk. It's not good to give an answer which is only directed towards one group of people. I would appreciate if you maybe edited your answer, so it would be satisfactory to those who installed through ROM.